# How to get certain posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, posts

I want to implement a function to get certain posts in wordpress.

**INPUT**

page_number

category_name

**VARIABLE**

items_per_page = 10

**OUTPUT**

posts array, like the result of the query_posts() function.

Here is my code:

```
$page_number = $_GET["page_number"]
$category_name = $_GET["category_name"]

function app_get_posts($page_number, $category,$items_per_page = 10)
{
    global $wpdb;  
    $select ="SELECT POSTS FROM wp_posts  WHERE CATEGORY = ".$category." LIMIT (".$page_number." - 1) * ".$items_per_page.",".$page_number."  * ".$items_per_page; //it didn't work.
    return $wpdb->query($select); 
}
```

When I call the function app_get_posts('2','tech'), it will return the 10th~19th posts in the "tech" category, when I call app_get_posts('3','wordpress'), it will return the 20th~29th posts in the "wordpress" category.

So I am wondering if there is a way to figure out this problem.
Thx in advence.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason why the above won't work is because the `wp_posts` table not has a `CATEGORY` or `POSTS` field. I modified you code so you can return posts based on `taxonomy`:

```
function app_get_posts($page_number, $category,$items_per_page = 10)
{
   global $wpdb;  
   $start = ($page_number-1) * $items_per_page;
   $select ="SELECT DISTINCT wp.* FROM wp_posts wp  
             INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships rs ON rs.object_id = wp.ID 
             INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = rs.term_taxonomy_id 
             WHERE t.name = ".$category." LIMIT ".$start.",".$items_per_page;
   return $wpdb->query($select); 
 }
```

Comment: Krister,thanks a lot.But when I use "$array =  app_get_posts('2','ca',2);
echo count($array);",it will always return 1.:-(  ps. Is the "wp" the name of wordpress's database?

Comment: @ellic - In the above query I'm using an alias named `wp` for the `wp_posts` table. Read more about aliases: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455%28v=sql.90%29.aspx